# Get cell indices of an item selected from drop down list

Tags: excel

How do I get the cell indicies of an item selected from a drop down list in Excel?

As an example of what I am trying to do consider the screenshot below. I want to allow a user to select a date from the drop down list, and then have the number adjacent to that date appear under the column headed "Corresponding number".

[image: Screenshot of example spreadsheet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `VLOOKUP`, assuming dates are in `A2:A13` and numbers in `B2:B13` use this formula in `D2`

`=IF(C2="","",VLOOKUP(C2,A$2:B$13,2,0))`

Comment: You could also use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,A$2:B$13,2,0), "")` for Excel 2007+.